# The year appears every 12 lines, but I want on all lines

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have an odd problem. Look at `df`:

```
Year <- c(1994, rep("NA", 11),1995,rep("NA",11))
Month <-c(1:12, 1:12)

df <- data.frame(Year,Month)
```

The year appears every 12 lines, but I want on all lines, like:

```
Year <- c(rep(1994, 12), rep(1995,12))
Month <-c(1:12, 1:12)

df_2 <- data.frame(Year,Month)
```

```
> df_2

   Year Month
1  1994     1
2  1994     2
3  1994     3
4  1994     4
5  1994     5
6  1994     6
7  1994     7
8  1994     8
9  1994     9
10 1994    10
11 1994    11
12 1994    12
13 1995     1
14 1995     2
15 1995     3
16 1995     4
17 1995     5
18 1995     6
19 1995     7
20 1995     8
21 1995     9
22 1995    10
23 1995    11
24 1995    12
```

I was trying a loop approach, but I wasn't able to solve this.
**PS:** this `df` goes until 2020, so the Month column goes until 11 in 2020.

I appreciate it if someone can help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can have `NA` without the quotes, and use `fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   mutate(Year = na_if(Year, "NA")) %>%
   fill(Year)
```

-output

```
#    Year Month
#1  1994     1
#2  1994     2
#3  1994     3
#4  1994     4
#5  1994     5
#6  1994     6
#7  1994     7
#8  1994     8
#9  1994     9
#10 1994    10
#11 1994    11
#12 1994    12
#13 1995     1
#14 1995     2
#15 1995     3
#16 1995     4
#17 1995     5
#18 1995     6
#19 1995     7
#20 1995     8
#21 1995     9
#22 1995    10
#23 1995    11
#24 1995    12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in base R this way:

```
yr <- rep(1994:2020, each = 12)
yrs <- length(1994:2020)
mth <- rep(1:12, yrs)
df <- data.frame(cbind(yr, mth))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with package `zoo`.

First of all, make the *strings* `"NA"` real `NA` values.

```
is.na(df$Year) <- df$Year == "NA"
```

Now fill down, the default of function `na.locf`.

```
df$Year <- zoo::na.locf(df$Year)
```